# How can I extract links from HTML?

Tags: html, sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I want to extract URLs from HTML to store in a CLOB datatype within an Oracle database.

Part of the HTML file looks like this:

```
<a class="href_class" href="/download/file.zip"></a>
```

I only need to take this part from HTML: `/download/file.zip` and put all the download links in the database. How, in regexp, can I indicate that the class name is matching a specific value like `href_class`?

I want to know what is the best way to resolve this problem with regexp or some other methods?

Comment: Now I have the solution: 
replace(regexp_substr(html, '(href="/download/)\w+\W+(zip){1}'), 'href="', '')
but I want to konw any suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since html is a structured document, you can load it as an `XMLType` in oracle and apply the appropriate `xpath` expressions to get the information required:

```
declare 
    html CLOB := '<html><a class="href_class" href="/download/file.zip"></a><a class="href_class" href="/download/file2.zip"></a></html>';
    xml XMLType;
    idx NUMBER := 1; 
begin
    xml := XMLType(html);
    WHILE xml.existsNode('//a[@class=''href_class''][' || idx || ']/@href') = 1 LOOP
        dbms_output.put_line(xml.extract('//a[@class=''href_class''][' || idx || ']/@href').getStringVal());
        idx := idx + 1;
    END LOOP;
end;
```

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/t_xml.htm#BABHCHHJ